# App crashes when I try to launch in Android Kitkat 4.4.4 but works fine in Android 5 & 6 versions

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, notificationmanager

I am new to `android`, and i am unable understand what exactly going on here, app works fine **`Android` 5 & 6** but crashes in `Android` 4(**`KITKAT`**)

```
03-13 13:11:44.925 10802-10840/? E/GoogleConversionPing: Error sending ping 03-13 13:11:45.145 3289-3497/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app 03-13 13:11:45.145 3289-3497/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras? 03-13 13:11:45.228 10802-10802/? E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null 03-13 13:11:46.710 650-650/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History> 03-13 13:11:46.741 650-650/? E/NotificationService: unable to notify listener (posted): android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@4249a880
                                                    android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
                                                        at android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy.onNotificationPosted(INotificationListener.java:102)
                                                        at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$NotificationListenerInfo.notifyPostedIfUserMatch(NotificationManagerService.java:264)
                                                        at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$2.run(NotificationManagerService.java:837)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                        at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1447)
                                                        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1542)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-13 13:11:53.368 650-1010/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation 03-13 13:11:53.398 650-650/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation 03-13 13:11:53.608 650-825/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation 03-13 13:11:53.636 650-650/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation 03-13 13:12:01.735 650-650/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History> 03-13 13:12:01.743 650-650/? E/NotificationService: unable to notify listener (posted): android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@4249a880
                                                    android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
                                                        at android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy.onNotificationPosted(INotificationListener.java:102)
                                                        at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$NotificationListenerInfo.notifyPostedIfUserMatch(NotificationManagerService.java:264)
                                                        at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$2.run(NotificationManagerService.java:837)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                        at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1447)
                                                        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1542)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:**

android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
}``
...
```

}

*dependencies {   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' }*

```
 public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

> Application extends SomeOtherApplication {   @Override   protected
>   void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
>        super.attachBaseContext(base);
>        MultiDex.install(this);   } }

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OP mutated the question since it was answered, so this answer does no 
longer apply.

The class `android.app.job.JobScheduler` was added in API level 21 (Android 5.0). It is therefore clear that the app would crash on earlier Android versions.

Comment: so, whats the solution i should be doing? Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using FCM Notification in my app too is it related to it ?

Answer (score 0):

`JobScheduler` isn't backported, however, there's the [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) that supports the same API and is backported via `Google Play Services`.

> The Firebase JobDispatcher is a library for scheduling background jobs
>   in your Android app. It provides a JobScheduler-compatible API that
>   works on all recent versions of Android (API level 9+) that have
>   Google Play services installed.

Comment: so, whats the solution i should be doing? Thanks in advance  and i am using FCM Notification in my app too is it related to it ?

Comment: see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#installation on how to add dependency to the new JobDispatcher, and see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#usage on how to use it. It's very similar to using `JobScheduler`. You can post your current code in your question if you need more specific help.

Comment: oh, and it's not related to FCM Notifications, but they're both part of the same firebase framework.